# Opencv video capture Error:ret, frame = cap.read()

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-capture

I am trying to make an application that makes use of the webcam to get the video. But I run the program, I am getting the following error: unkown c++ exception from opencv code.

My code is

```
Import cv2

Import mediapipe as mp 

cap = cv2.VedioCapture(0)

while True:

      ret, frame=cap.read()

      cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
      cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I am getting an error

```
ret, frame = cap.read()

Error: unknown c++ exception  from opencv code.
```

I am getting this error and frame opens but gray then.The camera open a frame and it blocks:frame not responding.

There is an error related to accessing the camera,but I found that my camera was working well and also has provided permissions to all app.
Also after running this program i found my flash was on so I released the camera,but unable to capture video.

Comment: `VedioCapture` does not exist. did you mean `VideoCapture`

Comment: **also**, you **must** check for errors. `assert cap.isOpened()` once right after creating the object. and then you must check `if not ret: break` after every cap.read. and you should discard whatever guides you follow since they didn't show you this.

Comment: what operating system is this?